# why sem_wait always returns 0 ? Does it mean it never fails?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, semaphore

While reading about semphores I read  this statement "**sem_wait always returns 0"**. Does it mean it never fails ?

Source :
Please refer slide no 5
http://os.itec.kit.edu/downloads/sysarch09-mutualexclusionADD.pdf

int sem_wait(sem_t *sem)
return value always 0 (cannot fail)

Comment: "this statement" -- which statement? Where is the source?

Answer (score 0):

Some digging has led me to think that there are two conditions for sem_wait() to fail:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19120-01/open.solaris/816-5137/sync-255/index.html

In practice, unless you are passing a bad address or the call gets interrupted, you should see 0 for your return value.

Comment: The question is about linux, so [this man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_wait.3.html) is more relevant. It says the same though.